# bash: How to pass arguments containing spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell, arguments

I have two bash scripts as below:

```
#main.sh
#!/bin/bash

files="file1 \"abc $1\" \"def $1\""

./upload.sh $files
```

```
#upload.sh
#!/bin/bash
for param in "$@"; do
    echo "${param}"
done
```

I'm trying to pass an argument containing a space to `main.sh` with the command as below:

```
edeMacBook-Pro:doc Yves$ ./main.sh "Sri Lanka"
```

I think `$files` will be like this: `file1 "abc Sri Lanka" "def Sri Lanka"`. So when I do `./upload.sh $files`, three arguments should be passed to `upload.sh`.

However, when I execute the command, I get:

```
file1
"abc
Sri
Lanka"
"def
Sri
Lanka"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to build a single string that "looks like" a string with all the arguments (which you could then try to `eval` if you really want to go that route) try using an array:

```
files=("file1" "abc $1" "def $1")
upload.sh "${files[@]}"
```